# Redirect http request but leave the url unchanged in chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, http, google-chrome-extension

I am making a chrome extension that is connected to my own server to make some requests. When a user navigates to `https://www.reddit.com/user/[username]/saved/`, I would like to keep the url the users sees, but instead make a request to my own server and return different `HTML`. So, the user wouldn't make a request to the reddit server to serve the `HTML` page, but rather to my own server where I would return a custom `HTML` for the page.

Is there a way to do this? I wanted to make a content-script that listens to `onBeforeRequest` and could serve another HTML page, but listening to every single request reduces performance.

Comment: The URL can't be changed  independently. You can call `window.stop()` in the content script, fetch the substituted content in the background script and send it in a message to the content script, which will either use document.write to rewrite the entire page or parse the html using DOMParser API and replace document.documentElement explicitly.

Comment: BTW webRequest listeners can have filters by URL and types of request so you can limit it to a particular URL which won't reduce performance, see the [webRequest documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest).